# specifying @selector for method on another object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Quick question, is there a way to specify a @selector that is a method on another object. Currently I have fudged a solution by using a local method to call the remote method, but it feels clunky.

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:self selector:@selector(timerLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]];
```

.

```
- (void)timerLocation {
    [[self dataModel] startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's what the `target` portion of the [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` method is for. (i.e.: You specify the object you want to call as the target and the name of the object's method as the selector.)

Comment: Expanding on the thought here, a selector is not a function pointer. It is a message name. It is not tied to any particular class. That's why you need to pass both the target and the selector. To avoid typos, I typically recommend passing -Wselector (the "Undeclared Selector" warning) to make sure your @selector() really exists somewhere in the system at compile time (this doesn't ensure at the selector is valid for the class it's passed to, just that it exists). In that case, you will generally need to #include the header of your target object.

Answer (score 2):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10 target:someOtherObject selector:@selector(timerLocation) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```